# what is the difference between "demand" and "ask"

Tags: word-meaning

Is there a difference in the meaning between the two words 'demand' and 'ask'
or there's no difference between it? could anyone tell me ?

Comment: Did you check a dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

The connotation of *demand* is **much** stronger. One might also use the weaker *require*, e.g., "I asked for an answer. I *require* an answer soon. In fact , I **demand** an immediate answer!"

Of course, *demand* has other meanings, e.g., "Air conditioners placed a heavy *demand* for power during the heat wave."

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that there are also some grammatical differences.  They ask *for* food; they demand food.  You can also "ask a question" or "ask Julie" but you can't really "demand a question", and "demand Julie" means something very different from "ask Julie".